# Decision tree classification preformance-good or bad?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, jupyter, decision-tree

I have a database of road accidents. I needed to build a classification decision tree in order to find interesting information between the features. I have 3 categorical features-'Accseverity', 'Shift', 'Day' - but when I use one of these feature as my target variable, I  get a tree with numeric classification. I want the tree to handle these categorical features in a way without numbers or at least without float values.
I used one-ho encoding to fit my categorical features to the tree.

1.setting my features
my features

> features=["SK_Tik_Teuna","Hour", "Year","Month","DriversInvolved","Jewish","UnknownReligon","NotJewish","UnknownCar","Else","Empty","Distric","Lighing","Urban_NotUrban","Crossroads_NotCrossroads","Coordinates","Area","AccSeverity_A","AccSeverity_B","AccSeverity_C","Day_D1","Day_D2","Day_D3","Day_D4","Day_D5","Day_D6","Day_D6","Day_D7","Shift_A","Shift_B","Shift_C"]

2.Building decision tree
decision tree classification

```
     print("Training size: {}; Test size: {}".format(len(train),len(test)) )
```

```
#result from the line above
Training size: 2024; Test size: 998

#define the tree parameters

    c=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini',

    min_samples_leaf=5,

    min_samples_split=5,

max_depth=None,
random_state=0)
```

3. one hot encoding
   one-hot-encoder to fix the categorical features

```
    data = data.copy()
    data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['AccSeverity'], prefix = ['AccSeverity'])
    data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['Day'], prefix = ['Day'])
    data = pd.get_dummies(data, columns=['Shift'], prefix = ['Shift'])
    print(data.head())
```

4. Checking data after encoding
   check data

> data.info()
>       
>       RangeIndex: 3022 entries, 0 to 3021
>       Data columns (total 40 columns):
>       SK_Tik_Teuna                3022 non-null int64
>       Hour                        3022 non-null int64
>       Year                        3022 non-null int64
>       Month                       3022 non-null int64
>       DriversInvolved             3022 non-null int64
>       Jewish                      3022 non-null int64
>       UnknownReligon              3022 non-null int64
>       NotJewish                   3022 non-null int64
>       UnknownCar                  3022 non-null int64
>       Else                        3022 non-null int64
>       Two_Third_Wheel             3022 non-null int64
>       Tender                      3022 non-null int64
>       Tractor                     3022 non-null int64
>       ATV                         3022 non-null int64
>       Unknown                     3022 non-null int64
>       Cab                         3022 non-null int64
>       CommercialVehicle           3022 non-null int64
>       Truck                       3022 non-null int64
>       PrivateCar                  3022 non-null int64
>       PublicVehicle               3022 non-null int64
>       Empty                       3022 non-null int64
>       Distric                     3022 non-null int64
>       Lighing                     3022 non-null int64
>       Urban_NotUrban              3022 non-null int64
>       Crossroads_NotCrossroads    3022 non-null int64
>       Coordinates                 3022 non-null int64
>       Area                        3022 non-null int64
>       AccSeverity_A               3022 non-null uint8
>       AccSeverity_B               3022 non-null uint8
>       AccSeverity_C               3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D1                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D2                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D3                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D4                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D5                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D6                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Day_D7                      3022 non-null uint8
>       Shift_A                     3022 non-null uint8
>       Shift_B                     3022 non-null uint8
>       Shift_C                     3022 non-null uint8
>       dtypes: int64(27), uint8(13)

5. set a target variable

```
x_train=train[features]
y_train=train["AccSeverity_A"]
x_test=test[features]
y_test=test["AccSeverity_A"]
```

```
#train
dt=c.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

6. Tree -output 
   build tree

```
    def show_tree(tree,features, path):
        f=io.StringIO()
        export_graphviz(tree,out_file=f, feature_names=features)
        pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(f.getvalue()).write_png(path)
        img=misc.imread(path)
        plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(20,20)
        plt.imshow(img)
```

> #show tree
>       #show_tree(dt, features, 'dec_tree_01.png')

```
#predict
y_pred=c.predict(x_test)
#rsult after running the line above
y_pred
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,
  1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8)

#accuracy finding
 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
 score=accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) *100
print("Accuracy using Desicion Tree:", round(score, 1), "%")

#result
#Accuracy using Desicion Tree: 100.0 %
```

Comment: Please, please format this properly. Additionally, your title is not matching the question I found in the body.

Comment: Im trying. My first question here so...sorry. unfortunately, I got blocked  for 1 day:(

Comment: It appears that you've dumped your entire project here, as well as the full tree you've built.  The only interrogative I see is whether your first stage of work is good or bad.  You've given us no discussion, no focus, no analysis, ... what sort of guidance do you need?  Is Stack Overflow the proper spot to ask?  Please check [Which site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your target variable is part of the input.

Of course you get 100% if the answer is already there...

Your tree probably consists of a single node that is equivalent to:

```
return AccSeverity_A
```